# How to rename database file programmatically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have two databases:

- `database_A`. Name of file is `database_A.mdf`.
- `database_B`. Name of file is `database_B.mdf`.

Then I what I do:

1. `Drop database_A`.
2. Rename `database_B` to `database_A`: `sp_renamedb 'database_B','database_A`.

However, name of file is still `database_B.mdf`.

**Is it possible just by code rename `database_B.mdf` to `database_A.mdf` without setting path to location of databases? I cannot use Management Studio to deattach database.**

Something like this but, without setting path name:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name
   MODIFY FILE ( NAME = logical_file_name, 
                 FILENAME = ' new_path/os_file_name_with_extension ' )
```

I don't know whether it will help to clarify why I want it, however, I will try why I need it. It is necessary to me because when I will create `database_A`, then I will get this error:

> Cannot create file '...\database_A.mdf' because it already exists.

**Is it possible just by code rename `database_B.mdf` to `database_A.mdf` without setting path to location of databases? I cannot use Management Studio to deattach database.**

Comment: No, you have to move the files, like you showed. Renaming the database doesn't change the names of its files.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the answer. By moving file, you mean this code `ALTER DATABASE database_name
   MODIFY FILE ( NAME = logical_file_name, 
                 FILENAME = ' new_path/os_file_name_with_extension ' )`?

Comment: That's the one.

Comment: Note that you can GET the path to the file, and then update it, and then use the updated path to move/rename it. So you don't HAVE to hard-code anything.

Comment: There's a pretty complete step by step process [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1891/steps-to-rename-a-sql-server-database/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to change file name of your database you will read this content

[Renaming Physical Database File Names](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4419/renaming-physical-database-file-names-for-a-sql-server-database/)

when your database attach in database service you cant change the name of database file.

becuase the database service used the data and log file.

you will be set data base singel user and set offline state for your database then change file name with

```
ALTER DATABASE XXX MODIFY FILE (Name='XXX', FILENAME='F:\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\XXX_Renamed.mdf')
```

you will be set your data base state offline and then change your file name and set state online with new file name and object browser file name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample SQL that will programmatically grab the mdf and ldf paths so that you can use them to do the rename without having to hard-code a path or file name. It also grabs the logical filenames. This isn't the full answer, this is the first part of the answer:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @params nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @dataFileName sysname;
DECLARE @logFileName sysname;
DECLARE @mdfFile nvarchar(400);
DECLARE @ldfFile nvarchar(400);
-- Get mdf and ldf file names
SET @params = '@mdfOUT nvarchar(400) OUTPUT, @ldfOut nvarchar(400) OUTPUT, @dataFileNameOUT sysname OUTPUT, @logFileNameOUT sysname OUTPUT'
SET @sql = N' SELECT @mdfOUT = physical_name FROM sys.database_files WHERE type = 0; ' +
           N' SELECT @ldfOUT = physical_name FROM sys.database_files WHERE type = 1; ' + 
           N' SELECT @dataFileNameOUT = [name] FROM sys.database_files WHERE type = 0; ' + 
           N' SELECT @logFileNameOUT = [name] FROM sys.database_files WHERE type = 1; ' 
EXEC sp_ExecuteSql @sql, @params, @mdfOUT=@mdfFile OUTPUT, @ldfOUT=@ldfFile OUTPUT, 
                   @dataFileNameOUT=@dataFileName OUTPUT, @logFileNameOUT=@logFileName OUTPUT;
SELECT @dataFileName AS [DataFileName], @mdfFile AS [mdf_File], @logFileName AS [LogFileName], @ldfFile AS [ldf_File]
```

Comment: oh, thank you very much for your answer! Could you write the complete solution?

Comment: Could you say how can I get physical address of `database_A`?

Comment: @Learner the compelete solution is available at link in my answer

Comment: @Learner you can find the physical address of database with two command first sp_helpfile `USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
EXEC sp_helpfile;` and twice is `SELECT * FROM sys.database_files`

Comment: @Learner you view the properties of your database in sql server management studio